Adafruit_binascii lib
The error :
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 31, in <module>
 File "adafruit_rsa/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
 File "adafruit_rsa/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
 File "adafruit_rsa/key.py", line 32, in <module>
 File "adafruit_rsa/pem.py", line 13, in <module>
 ImportError: no module named 'adafruit_binascii.a2b_base64'

I added the library for circuitpython 9.1.1 but it does not detect this module and I couldnt found it inside the library bundle
Zip file library for adafruit_binascii.a2b_base64

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
